# How an user of my application can delete sharedpreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, anti-cheat

I'm developing an app that use SharePreferences in order to avoid user cheating.
But how an user can delete sharedPreferences?

There is a better method to save data like SharePreferences that is more secure?

Answer (score 1):

One way is for the user to uninstall the application, then re-install it. Unless you maintain data somewhere else, such as a hidden file elsewhere on the device, I'm not sure there's any way to get around that.

Comment: Against the uninstall, obviously we can't do nothing, but on clear data app in the app settings?

Comment: You could try using external storage, which I think means "external to your app" rather than "external to the device." You can save it to a public directory with an innocuous name, perhaps even in a hidden form (e.g., ".data"). https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Answer (score 1):

Consider using internal storage on the device. Only your app will have access to it. [visit this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

you can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) about the security of storage options